# GUI based options: Advanced Archiving "Zip 7z etc..."

Tags: settings, archive, compression, 7zip

Does a graphical archive manager exist for linux that has the advanced settings that 7z and others have on windows?

Something with settings like "Use here as temp" "thread count to use" "Memory to use".

I want to start compressing my massive download and etc data into contiguous files.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, The default Archive manager, [File Roller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/File%20Roller) is present; Which is really efficient and comparable to the performance of 7zip under windows.

On the official [download page](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) of 7zip, you may also find alternatives for Linux (approximately in the middle of the page).

You may also run your windows softwares inside Ubuntu using the [Wine Software](http://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: Im sure they are easy to use programs. I do use them. As for usage under wine, as I understand, Multithreading is a bit of a "maybe" concept.

Comment: Yes, they are very easy to use.. and using them under wine is also extremely easy.. Once you install wine, the .exe apps will be handled the way windows does.

Comment: Dear down-voter to this answer, may you please suggest some other alternative to this in order to justify your down-vote  :-\

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still look for GUI based archiver for linux, there is also a PeaZip linux version. You can find it [here](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/peazip-linux.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to post a direct comment to an answer, So i will use this box. (probly the right one, maybe not.) 
But Mr. Z9iT, Using wine is very easy, Yes. But I recall from a conversation I had on IRC some time ago, There are certain DLLs(I think its DLLs) That are either modified or somehow re-suited to wine to be, how did he put it...
"Posix compatible" or "thread safe" Which I took to mean it could be multi-threaded.
 

I know that one programs Will not allow for this in wine because it is not as so, "safe" to thread. Ergo, using A compression program may not work correctly, or will only work on a single core which would seriously slow the process.

Answer (score -2):

The Archive Manager (default) is certainly one of the easy GUI archive manager available in Ubuntu right now. Or to find one with the specific options you need, you might have to look in the Software Center.

Comment: Thankyou for your time MCan, I did look into the software center, I still cant find anything. I expect if it exists, its in other repositories.